# highcharts <path> attribute d: Expected number

Tags: highcharts, numbers

[The running case](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2WRkU.jpg)I met a problem in customizing a dynamic update chart. here is my code.

```
                    load : function () {
                var series = this.series[0];
                    time2 = setInterval(function () {
                    var flag = true;
                        if ($('#pause:checked').length > 0) flag = false;    
                    var x = (new Date()).getTime(), // current time
                        y = Math.round(Math.random() * 100);
                        xValue = x;
                        yValue = y;
                    series.addPoint([x, y], flag, flag);
                    console.log(xValue + ",  " + yValue);
                    if(flag){
                    document.getElementById("currentFrequency").innerHTML = (x + "  ");
                    document.getElementById("currentDb").innerHTML = (y + "  ");
                    document.getElementById("currentFrequency2").innerHTML = (x);
                    }
                }, 100);
            }, // -> function load over
```

The error says: highstock.js:59 Error:  attribute d: Expected number, "…0.5325987144169 C 0 20.532598714…".
The way generating the random data is exactly the same way as what was showing in the official demo. The problem is likely to occur when set the interval lower than 1000.
Anyone can figure out what went wrong? thanks a lot.

Comment: It would be easier to investigate your issue if you would post live example of your issue. Like jsFiddle. In this case your problem may be connected with redrawing your charts to fast after previous redraw, adding points outside your chart extremes etc.